# How to see what's using battery right now?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, battery, lumia-950, diagnostics

Occasionally I've noticed a problem with my Lumia 950 where it gets rather hot and the battery discharges very quickly (10-15% per hour), even when the phone is not in use. This happens very infrequently, which makes debugging difficult. I've looked at the battery use report, but it only offers three time frames - 24 hours, 48 hours and 1 week. Even with the first option, the data is often heavily skewed by some resource-intensive app (e.g. a game) that is no longer running. Is there any way to see what's using battery power *right now*, as the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Task Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/task-manager-lite/9nblggh5jpjc) app which is similar to the native PC version. It displays what background processes are running (in the background) and you can terminate them too.

P.S. There's an app called [Battery X](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/battery-x/9nblggh4wlgx) , it is good with tracking your battery's usage, strength, performance etc.

Comment: The mobile task manager UWP app is a much better choice though. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mobile-task-manager/9nblggh6hfv1#